# OpenCL/CUDA: Two-stage reduction Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, opencl

Reduction of large arrays can be done by calling __reduce(); multiple times.

The following code however uses only two stages and is documented [here](http://developer.amd.com/Membership/Print.aspx?ArticleID=221&web=http://developer.amd.com/documentation/articles):

However I am unable to understand the algorithm for this two stage reduction.  can some give a simpler explanation?

```
__kernel
void reduce(__global float* buffer,
        __local float* scratch,
        __const int length,
        __global float* result) {

    int global_index = get_global_id(0);
    float accumulator = INFINITY;
    // Loop sequentially over chunks of input vector
    while (global_index < length) {
        float element = buffer[global_index];
        accumulator = (accumulator < element) ? accumulator : element;
        global_index += get_global_size(0);
    }

    // Perform parallel reduction
    int local_index = get_local_id(0);
    scratch[local_index] = accumulator;
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    for(int offset = get_local_size(0) / 2; offset > 0; offset = offset / 2) {
        if (local_index < offset) {
            float other = scratch[local_index + offset];
            float mine = scratch[local_index];
            scratch[local_index] = (mine < other) ? mine : other;
        }
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    }
    if (local_index == 0) {
        result[get_group_id(0)] = scratch[0];
    }
}
```

It can also be well implemented using CUDA.

Comment: This parallel reduction code is a straightforward OpenCL port of the canonical CUDA reduction (lacking a couple of optimisations which OpenCL can't do). It was written by [Mark Harris](http://stackoverflow.com/users/749748/harrism) of NVIDIA. You can find a very instructive whitepaper on the algorithm in the CUDA SDK [reduction example](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-cc-sdk-code-samples#reduction). After you have read that whitepaper, edit your question to explain what it is you don't understand and someone might be able to help further.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to right direction. Well I am facing difficulty in understanding difference between two-stage and multi stage reduction kernel as given [here](http://developer.amd.com/Membership/Print.aspx?ArticleID=221&web=http://developer.amd.com/documentation/articles)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create `N` threads. The first thread looks at values at positions 0, N, 2*N, ... The second thread looks at values 1, N+1, 2*N+1, ... That's the first loop. It reduces `length` values into N values.

Then each thread saves its smallest value in shared/local memory. Then you have a synchronization instruction (`barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE)`.) Then you have standard reduction in shared/local memory. When you're done the thread with local id 0 saves its result in the output array.

All in all, you have a reduction from `length` to `N/get_local_size(0)` values. You'd need to do one last pass after this code is done executing. However, this gets most of the job done, for example, you might have length ~ 10^8, N = 2^16, get_local_size(0) = 256 = 2^8, and this code reduces 10^8 elements into 256 elements.

Which parts do you not understand?

Comment: Hi, I too am stuck in reduction process. Well I am trying to implement sorting algorithms in OpenCL. The problem is, I can comfortably apply reduction in the local memory, which is no sweat to many. What I am unable to do is to reduce/merge/combine the sorted arrays present in the local array to one large fully sorted array. Offcourse I can run the sorting algorithms on global memory at the end but I dont think it is the way to do. Please help me......

Comment: I had my problems understanding this, too. The way I understand it this kernel reduces the problem to `get_num_groups(0)` elements. Which would be `get_global_size(0)/get_local_size(0)` And is defined by the NDRange, that is set when the kernel is enqueued. So host code is essential to this kernel, but sadly never provided on the original AMD page. I figure a NDRange that matches `CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS * CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` would do the trick of maxing parallelism of sequential parts. Correct me if I am wrong.